# Re-wiring OBD port

Tags: obd-ii, automotive-design, obd

I was reading online about thieves 'hacking' the OBD2 port on push button start vehicles and there seems to be little discussion around OBD2 port locks or moving OBD ports.
I was wondering if any has attempted to rewire an OBD2 port with a proprietary 16 pin connector and just connecting a dongle when they need to use it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Swap the CAN lines and make an adapter harness when you need to connect, I have heard of plenty people doing this to avoid thieves as well as manufacturer warranty voids after tuning.

Answer (score 1):

pin 16 can be spliced with a hidden switch in case you need it on. You can also reroute pin 16 to be switched by rerouting it to the main power relay so that when the car is off, power is off on pin 16. However, if you have a "pay as you go" device form your Insurance company, this may be a problem as they cannot read your position at rest.

Comment: Hey Nitro,

Thanks for joining the Mechanics Stack Exchange!
Good info here, always great to have new people coming in with good answers.

Generally for Answers more structured formatting would be ideal, if you look around at other highly rated answers you'll be able to see some examples of how to format most answers.